# getting x,y coordinators from Jquery ui draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, coordinates, draggable

I am trying to get the coordinates of a draggable div that I used jquery-ui to make and in the jquery files I found the function that returns the position but whenever I try to console the position I get this error , is there any way that i can get the coordinates ?:

```
> Unexpected token (
```

This is the code for the x,y retrial:

```
    _getRelativeOffset: function() {
            if ( this.cssPosition !== "relative" ) {
                return { top: 0, left: 0 };
            }

            var p = this.element.position(),
                scrollIsRootNode = this._isRootNode( this.scrollParent[ 0 ] );

            return {
                top: p.top - ( parseInt(this.helper.css( "top" ), 10) || 0 ) + ( !scrollIsRootNode ? this.scrollParent.scrollTop() : 0 ),
                left: p.left - ( parseInt(this.helper.css( "left" ), 10) || 0 ) + ( !scrollIsRootNode ? this.scrollParent.scrollLeft() : 0 )

            console.log(p.top);

            };

        }
```

and in another php/html file i used this div i am not sure if this is the correct use of it   :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

  });


  </script>
```

and if i can do this to be able to get the coordinates

Comment: You cannot have a `console.log` call inside your object declaration. Place the `console.log` above your return statement.

Comment: Please edit this question with the full content of the file containing this snippet. Is `_getRelativeOffset: function() {` the first line in your js file?

Comment: yes it is the first line it is in a whole separate file and _getRelativeOffset: function() { is the first line

Comment: That's not valid JS syntax, if you replace `_getRelativeOffset: function() {` with a function declaration - `function _getRelativeOffset () {` - the error should dissaper. I don't know what do you want to do with the `_getRelativeOffset ` function, but that's another problem :)

Comment: thank you so much that indeed made the error go away and you are right that is a whole other problem because i though it will desolay the position but it did not sorry for the trouble i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
_getRelativeOffset: function() {
        if ( this.cssPosition !== "relative" ) {
            return { top: 0, left: 0 };
        }

        var p = this.element.position(),
            scrollIsRootNode = this._isRootNode( this.scrollParent[ 0 ] );

        // this should be placed here, not inside your object declaration
        console.log(p.top);

        return {
            top: p.top - ( parseInt(this.helper.css( "top" ), 10) || 0 ) + ( !scrollIsRootNode ? this.scrollParent.scrollTop() : 0 ),
            left: p.left - ( parseInt(this.helper.css( "left" ), 10) || 0 ) + ( !scrollIsRootNode ? this.scrollParent.scrollLeft() : 0 )
        };

    }
```

Comment: it still gives me the same error i have this function in another file that i attached to my main could this be in anyway the problem? thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't see other problems with the code you've provided. When did the error appear? Try to remove (comment out) some code until you find what causes the problem

Comment: the code i provided is a jquery code that was in the file attached to the draggable div i used i only added the console because i need to know the positions of the div i tried the correction you made refreshed the page still give me the same error and it says its in line :1 thank you for the help again and sorry for the trouble

Comment: there's no way I can find out where the problem resides, unless maybe you post the whole content of the file (not just the snippet you've provided). If that's not possible, try to remove (or comment out) pieces of code until you find the problem. Also make sure that the browser sees the updated js file (on chrome: empty cache and hard reload)

Comment: there is no much to it but i will try and post it

Comment: I meant the full content of the file containing the snippet you've provided (you can edit your question by the way, there's no need to post it in the comment section)

Comment: sorry i am totally new here

Comment: "you can edit your **question**", not my answer haha :)